# Is there a way to know a branch A was created based on which branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Lets Say I have a `dev` and `master` branch. And someone has created a new branch `featureA`.

Is there a way that I can find that `featureA` was created based on dev or master?

I tried using  `git log --oneline` to check if it will provide this info

not sure if is there a command for this or even if this info is stored somewhere.